# Excel VBA If 1 Row Don't Autofill Almost works

Tags: excel, vba

New to forum and very new to VBA.  I'm trying to consolidate data off hundreds of forms I get every month.  I have to grab a few extra fields off the forms (names, dates, stores) and fill down alongside the other columns. I've run into the error of when there is only one row of data and can't autofill.  I've tried to work around this with an IF, Then, Else.  What happens is after it hits a file that has that one row, it will not do the autofill on any subsequent files with more than one.  It almost works.

Code:

```
Sub test()
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim Erow
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

FolderPath = "C:\Users\Test\"
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")


    Do While FileName <> ""
    
    Workbooks.Open (FolderPath & FileName)
    Range("B10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K17").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("J9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L17").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("J11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M17").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Dim lastRow As Long
    If lastRow > 17 Then
    lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("K17").AutoFill Destination:=Range("K17:K" & lastRow), 
    Type:=xlFillCopy
    lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("L17").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L17:L" & lastRow), 
    Type:=xlFillCopy
    lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("M17").AutoFill Destination:=Range("M17:M" & lastRow), 
    Type:=xlFillCopy
    Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Range("A17:M200").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If

Erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(Erow, 1), Cells(Erow, 13))

FileName = Dir

Loop
End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of what happens after the "one row" file.

#### Error After One Row, Auto Fill stops

[image: Error After One Row, Auto Fill stops]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises from having the calculation for the lastrow within the IF statement. The lastrow is only recalculates when lastRow > 17 from the previous workbook.

Calculate lastrow before the IF statement, so that you're looking at the lastrow of the current workbook each time.

Comment: Worked.  Moved the If after the lastrow and everything filled down properly.  Thank you Michael!